# Does an extensions chrome.storage clear when it is updated?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've searched all over and can't seem to find a concrete answer anywhere nor in the [API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#property-local). I ran a test with "developer mode" turned on and then clicking the "update" extensions button and my chrome.storage.local was cleared.

I'm wondering if the extension auto update has the same affect on my users. When I publish a change to the extension will all of their local storage be cleared?

If so, what's the best way to get more persistent client side storage for the extension? I'm really looking to generate a unique ID when the extension is installed and have that ID persist across updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will be persistent between updates.

However, uninstalling an extension will clear the storage, including the sync storage.

Also, you could create a test version of your extension and upload it to the store (invisible for users) and test extension update behavior on it.

Comment: Even chrome.storage.local will persist between extension updates? or just sync?

Comment: Even `chrome.storage.loca`l will be the same.

Comment: Ok I'm going to do some more rigorous testing with the chrome store and I'll update this question accordingly. It just seems odd to me that the developer mode "update" would behave different than the auto update.

Comment: Ok so there was a piece of code in the background JS page that was clearing the storage lol. So that explains why every time the extension was refreshed, updated, etc the storage was cleared. Giving you the answer and vote since you were 100% correct and responsive.